# Could the WP script/style loader be used to concatenate and gzip scripts and styles in the front-end?

Tags: css, javascript, performance, wp-enqueue-script

WP has a nice javascript loader included in wp-admin:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/load-scripts.php

and a CSS loader:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/load-styles.php

I was wondering if it's possible to use them in the front-end too, not just admin, because they can concatenate all enqueued scripts, and serve them as a single gzipped file

Comment: Isn't this effectively just asking **"Can i use enqueues for non-admin pages?"** .. The answer to that would be Yes.

Comment: @t31os The question is if you can use load-scripts.php and load-styles to **concatenate and gzip** the styles and scripts like they are done for the admin.  I clarified the title of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*late answer*

From a brief look:

You'd have to use

- `include( admin_url().'load-scripts.php' );`
- and `include( admin_url().'script-loader.php' );`

Then jump into `$GLOBALS['wp_scripts']`:

Use…

```
$wp_scripts->default_dirs( array_merge( 
     $wp_scripts->default_dirs
    ,array( '/themes/your_theme/js/' ) 
);
```

…to extend it.

And then use

```
$wp_scripts->add( $handle, $path_from_content_dir, false/array( $deps ), $ver )
```

to add a script.

*Notes:*

1. Uncompressed scripts get searched by `.dev.js` (when `SCRIPT_DEBUG` is `TRUE`).
2. Same seems to be possible for `$wp_styles`.
3. EDIT: *WP 3.5* will change this behavior and use `.js` for "dev" versions and ".min.js" when (`SCRIPT_DEBUG` is `TRUE`);

(But I guess this will only work if you use a plugin or mu-plugin.)

<sub>It´s not tested and I´m not shure if this will work.</sub>

Comment: I'm currently trying to do something like this. Bad thing is that load-scripts.php has an `exit()` in the end so you can't do anything afterwards.

Comment: This answer actually saved me from a massive headache. If `SCRIPT_DEBUG` is `true`, all scripts are enqueued individually much like in the frontend. However, if `SCRIPT_DEBUG` is `false`, it seems to enqueue the scripts simultaneously through `load-scripts.php`.

Comment: @MichaelEcklund Yes, this "switch"–constant _concatenates_ or delivers single files. This is from the times before source maps and nowadays developer tools.

Answer (score 6):

### This is a very good question and would be a great feature for WordPress to include.

Some of the other answers don't address the main question.

> I was wondering if it's possible to
> use them in the front-end too, not
> just admin, because they can
> concatenate all enqueued scripts, and
> serve them as a single gzipped file.

No it's not currently possible to use the built in script loader to Concatenate css and scripts for the front end.

There was a [discussion about this on WP Hackers](http://old.nabble.com/Hook-into-load-styles.php---load-scripts.php-%22queue%22--td26596910.html) a few years ago and there is a [trac ticket for this enhancement](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14374) that has been accepted but for a future release.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to enqueue a CSS file on the front end:

1) Register the style via wp_register_style( $handle, $src )
2) Hook wp_enqueue_style( $handle ) into the wp_print_styles hook.

If you need to enqueue a script on the front end:

1) Register the style via wp_register_script( $handle, $src )
2) Hook wp_enqueue_script( $handle ) into the wp_head hook.

(Note: I would have expected the wp_print_styles hook for this, but this hook apparently does not work as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few scripts you may wish to look at.

**1. Combine.php** 
 - On a number of my themes I have implemented [this script](http://rakaz.nl/code/combine). It supports similar functionality and can be dropped into your template folder and worked with relatively easily.

**2. WP Minify**
 - [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) supports minifying and is very easily to work with.

**3. W3 Total Cache**
 -  is a very powerful performance plugin. It also supports script/css combination as well as a large number of other features e.g. off loading the combined scripts to a CDN.